# Why "dilatasti" instead of "dilatavisti" in Psalm 4:2?

Tags: verbs, conjunction, vulgata, perfect-tense

> (Psalm 4:2) cum invocarem exaudivit me Deus iustitiae meae in tribulatione **dilatasti** mihi miserere mei et exaudi orationem meam
>
> When I called upon him, the God of my justice heard me: when I was in distress, **thou hast enlarged** me. Have mercy on me: and hear my prayer.

From the context of the above Psalm verse, ***dilatasti*** seems to be 2nd-person singular perfect active indicative. Moreover, that is the parsing information given by [this site](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Psalm%204.2&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0060).

However, my Latin dictionary lists *dilatavi* as the third principal part, which means *dilatavi* is the 1st-person singular perfect active indicative. Therefore, it seems that ***dilatavisti*** would be the 2nd-person singular perfect active indicative. Moreover, [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilato#Latin) lists *dilatavisti* as the 2nd-person singular perfect active indicative.

Which is the correct form?

Comment: Some of these contracted verb forms, sometimes called 'syncopated.'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a **contracted perfect** form, which is fairly common in poetry, particularly in the first conjugation.

Basically, whenever you have a second person perfect active ending in *-āvisti* (like *amāvisti* "you loved"), it can be contracted to *-āsti* without changing the meaning (e.g. *amāsti* "you loved").

It's somewhat like how English uses "don't" instead of "do not": no change in meaning, but shorter, and sometimes fits the poetic meter better.

Comment: So they're both grammatically correct?

Comment: A handy guide to this and other kinds of contraction: https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/contractions.pdf

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Yep! Which one to use is really up to individual choice.

Comment: @Pascal'sWager This is also in the parsing information on Perseus: "contr" means contracted

Comment: It's also worth noting that these contracted forms are the ancestors of modern Romance forms, e.g., Spanish 2nd sg preterit _amaste_ from L. _amasti_.